# There is `Unexpected input given to normalize` error message in redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux

There is error in action in React+redux - application after recieved response
fronend ReactJS, backend java. After recieving response using fetch, I received error message:

> Error: Unexpected input given to normalize. Expected type to be
>   "object", found "undefined".

```
 @RequestMapping(value = {"/overtimes/divisions"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List getAllDivisions(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Payment> res = new ArrayList<>();
    res.add(new Payment());
    return res;
}
```

front-end api

```
export const fetchDivisions = () => invokeGetDivisions()
  .then(throwHttpErrors)
  .then(response =>
    response.json(),
  );

    const invokeGetDivisions = () => fetch("/rest/overtimes/divisions", {
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
  },
  method: "GET",
  credentials: "same-origin",
});
```

state: 
[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm having the same issue.